# .Net Multi threading accessing / changing local variables in a function

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

Application Design: 
Its a batch process (.Net 3.5)

EXE(Threading Tasks) -> WCF WebService -> Dll -> ... -> Dll -> ... Database

I have drilled down to the exact method where threads are mixing up data. A basic but exact representation of the method.

```
    Public Function Name(  TransactionArray (,) Object)

      Dim x As Decimal
      Dim y As Decimal

      <Loop TransactionArray>
        x= TransactionArray(0,0)
        y = TransactionArray(1,0)

        <AnotherClassObjectInstance>.CallAnotherMethod(X,Y) 'Add data to database 
      <End loop TransactionArray>

End Function
```

How I am sure threads are mixing up data.

1. looped and wrote the transaction array values to a log at the start of the function.
2. wrote X and Y to log as well.
3. Totally different values to what was in the transaction array and X and Y.

Tried following, but they did not work.

1. Directly used transaciton array to set value in  .CallAnotherMethod(X,Y)
2. Went to the top level dll function where TransactionArray is a local variable. Moved it to class level and made it shared and thread static.

Question
1. What more I can try ?
2. I should be looking at some other place?

Comment: Are you modifying the `TransactionArray` object from another thread? Then you need to add locks or other synchronization measures to ensure consistency.

Comment: And please be exact, what **exactly** does "mixing up data" mean here?

Comment: the exe is calling the top level wcf method using Tasks ( 28 instances simultaneously).
TransacitonArray: not modifying the TransactionArray from another thread. It actually has the correct values .

However when assigning to X and Y or after assigning to X and Y. They do not have the same value as in TransactionArray.


So X or Y or both have values from another thread.

Comment: I see no actual loop in the pseudo code, and no loop variables.

Comment: 'Loop ... 'EndLoop is the loop representation. Changed it a bit to make it more clearer

Comment: `X` and `Y` are *local* variables, they exist separately in each and every invocation of the function. Are you looking at their values when your debugger switches threads? (Debugging heavily concurrent code can be hard: Visual Studio's Threads window can help keep track.

Comment: I did do VS thread debug, its extremely difficult to recreate in debug mode.
I logged the values to log file , thats why I can say they are being changed even tough they are local variables.